# How can I recover last word of BIP-32/39 mnemonic copay second signature multisig wallet

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, p2sh, multi-signature, mnemonic-seed

I've got a multisig 2of2 wallet in copay.

I've one wallet correct but have lost second wallet and only have 11 of the 12 words of the seed.I'm pretty sure I miss the last one.
I've got some of the first created adresses and trying to recover using **btcrecover** but throws an error:

> The entered address is invalid (not a Bitcoin P2PKH address; verson byte is 0x05)

Copay uses P2SH addresses for multisig addresses and I don't know hot to proceed.

Any hints?

Comment: How do you know you have the first one correct? Are you trying to import it back into a copay wallet? You own both of the 2/2 wallets? Sounds like you might need to write a custom script that will try each of the words in the BIP-39 dictionary as the last word, generate the first pubkey in the standard HD key tree, combine it with the known key from the other wallet and see if you get the right P2SH address output. btcrecover is pretty good, but I don't think it can anticipate that use case.

Comment: I have the first wallet configured in my  smartphone and working. The second wallet was in a friend smartphone. He wanted to format it so he made an app backup with easy backup thinking that it would keep settings and wallet. 
Ok, now that I have some direction I will try to make the script. At least now I know what to search for in Google ;-) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

last word only have 128 possibilities
you can calculated by the first 11 words

Comment: And the details for doing this are here:  https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/97157/75119